# error:Required argument (index) missing to function: List.get(list, index)

Tags: google-earth-engine, sentinel-1

I have written a code in GEE retrieves images from sentinel 1 and suppose to display those images.
I have created a for loop that suppose to display those images but for some reason I am getting the error message:

> Required argument (index) missing to function: List.get(list, index)
>
> Returns the element at the specified position in list.  A negative
>   index counts backwards from the end of the list.
>
> Args:
>
> list (List): Undocumented.   index (Integer): Undocumented.
>
> Returns the element at the specified position in list.  A negative
>   index counts backwards from the end of the list.

I saw that this problem is common but I don't find the problem in my code that led to this error.

this is my code:

```
//var geometry=geometry2;


// Load the Sentinel-1 ImageCollection.
var sentinel1 = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S1_GRD');

// Filter by metadata properties.
var vh = sentinel1
  // Filter to get images VH dual polarization.
  .filter(ee.Filter.listContains('transmitterReceiverPolarisation', 'VH'))
  // Filter to get images collected in interferometric wide swath mode.
  .filter(ee.Filter.eq('instrumentMode', 'IW'))
    // reduce to VH polarization
  .select('VH')
   // filter 10m resolution
  .filter(ee.Filter.eq('resolution_meters', 10))
  .filterBounds(geometry);

  // Filter to get images from different look angles.
var vhDescending = vh.filter(ee.Filter.eq('orbitProperties_pass', 'DESCENDING'));
//var vhAscending = vh.filter(ee.Filter.eq('orbitProperties_pass', 'ASCENDING'));


//fiter date
var vhDesc = vhDescending.filterDate(ee.Date('2015-08-01'), ee.Date('2019-10-08'));
//var vhAsce = vhAscending.filterDate(ee.Date('2019-06-01'), ee.Date('2019-10-08'));

//clip the dataset according to the geometry
var clippedCol=vhDesc.map(function(im){ 
  return im.clip(geometry);
});

//count how many images we have in the collection-
var count=clippedCol.size();
print('Number of Images',count);



//create list of images
var ListDesc =(clippedCol.toList(clippedCol.size()));

var ListofNumbers=[0,1,2,3,5,17,20,28];


//display the images using loop
for (var i in ListofNumbers) {
  var image = ee.Image(ListDesc.get(ListDesc[i]));
  Map.addLayer(image,{}, i);

}
```

code update:

```
//var geometry=geometry2;


// Load the Sentinel-1 ImageCollection.
var sentinel1 = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S1_GRD');

// Filter by metadata properties.
var vh = sentinel1
  // Filter to get images VH dual polarization.
  .filter(ee.Filter.listContains('transmitterReceiverPolarisation', 'VH'))
  // Filter to get images collected in interferometric wide swath mode.
  .filter(ee.Filter.eq('instrumentMode', 'IW'))
    // reduce to VH polarization
  .select('VH')
   // filter 10m resolution
  .filter(ee.Filter.eq('resolution_meters', 10))
  .filterBounds(geometry);

  // Filter to get images from different look angles.
var vhDescending = vh.filter(ee.Filter.eq('orbitProperties_pass', 'DESCENDING'));
//var vhAscending = vh.filter(ee.Filter.eq('orbitProperties_pass', 'ASCENDING'));


//fiter date
var vhDesc = vhDescending.filterDate(ee.Date('2015-08-01'), ee.Date('2019-10-08'));
//var vhAsce = vhAscending.filterDate(ee.Date('2019-06-01'), ee.Date('2019-10-08'));

//clip the dataset according to the geometry
var clippedCol=vhDesc.map(function(im){ 
  return im.clip(geometry);
});

//count how many images we have in the collection-
var count=clippedCol.size();
print('Number of Images',count);



//create list of images
var ListDesc =(clippedCol.toList(clippedCol.size()));

var ListofNumbers=[0,1,2,3,5,17,20,28];


//display the images using loop
for (var i in ListofNumbers) {
  var image = ee.Image(ListDesc.get(ListofNumbers,i));
  Map.addLayer(image,{}, i);}
```

Comment: You are calling **ListDesc.map(...)** before defining **var ListDesc**

Comment: sorry I have put the wrong code, I edited it. and Now I get another error message- Required argument (index) missing to function: List.get(list, index)

Returns the element at the specified position in list.  A negative index counts backwards from the end of the list.

Args:

  list (List): Undocumented.
  index (Integer): Undocumented.

Comment: At the end of your code, you wrote **ListDesc.get(ListDesc[i])** but this function requires two arguments, first the list and then the index. I would suggest to try something like **ListDesc.get(ListDesc,i)** instead.

Comment: that didn't work

Comment: Ok, do you have the same error message ?

Comment: different, Too many (3) arguments to function: List.get(list, index)

Returns the element at the specified position in list.  A negative index counts backwards from the end of the list.

Args:

  list (List): Undocumented.
  index (Integer): Undocumented.

Comment: I don't understnd why does it say it has too many arguments

Comment: Can you update your code in the question to exactly what you have now ?

Comment: I have updated the code (under " updated")

Comment: Ok, according to the documentation ( https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/api_docs#ee.list.get ), I would replace the whole line **var image = ee.Image(ListDesc.get(ListofNumbers,i))** by **var image = ee.Image(ee.List.get(ListDesc,ListofNumbers[i]))** or  **var image = ee.Image(ListDesc.get(ListofNumbers[i]))**

Comment: For some reason, there seems to be an issue with for ... in ... loop. I tried using the for (var i =0; ........ ) loop, as i have done that a lot of times, and the code works without an issue. Also, the 2 arguments are 1. the object calling the function (which does not need to be specified) and 2. the index of object. So it takes only one argument on the script.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 issues here:

1. The documentation for `List.get` says:

> ee.List.get
>
> Returns the element at the specified position in list. A
>   negative index counts backwards from the end of the list.
>
> Usage Returns List.get(index) Object Argument Type    Details this:
>   list  List     index  Integer

2. when using the expression `for (var i in ListofNumbers)`, `i` is the index of the list, and not the element. So, you have to get the element using that index.

```js
var ListDesc = ee.List([
  ee.Image.constant(1), 
  ee.Image.constant(2),
  ee.Image.constant(3)])

var ListofNumbers = [0, 2];


//display the images using loop
for (var i in ListofNumbers) {
  var index = ListofNumbers[i]
  var image = ee.Image(ListDesc.get(index))
  Map.addLayer(image, {}, index.toString())
}
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/df59d380138a4e4b5a390376d6633d81

Comment: thank you for your answer, I didn't understand what is the first part (ListDec) that you have created, why is it composed of 3 images?

Comment: it's just an example of a list of images.. shouldn't be relevant to your question. If it is relevant, then the issue may come from there

Comment: yes I know it's an example, but if you could elaborate a little about it it will make it more clear for me

Comment: `var ListDesc = ee.List([ee.Image.constant(1),  ee.Image.constant(2), ee.Image.constant(3)])` should be a list of image just like your `var ListDesc =(clippedCol.toList(clippedCol.size()));`. Copy and paste my `for` loop to replace yours ans see how it goes